# std::string to std::bitset represented by std::string and vice-versa

Tags: c++, string, binary, bitset

Now-now this can be a little confusing but I can't come up with a more simple title that could tell exactly what I mean. I have a string that I wish to convert to binary (each char to 16bit width binary) STRING. And then the binary string back to the original string. I have no problems converting the string to its binary "string".

```
std::string original = "The lazy fox jumped upon the fancy fence.";
std::stringstream bStream;
for (int i = 0, iMAX = original.size(); i < iMAX; ++i) {
    bStream << std::bitset<16>(original[i]);
}
std::string binaryString = bStream.str();
```

How could I convert this binaryString back to original?

Cheers,
 Joey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
std::string bin2str(std::string t_)
{
    std::stringstream bStream(t_);
    std::string ret;
    std::bitset<16> t;
    while(bStream >> t) {
        ret += static_cast<char>(t.to_ulong());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly and fast, thanks for your help! I totally forgot about stringstream.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
std::string originalBack = ""; // result saved there
for (int i = 0; i < binaryString.size() / 16; i++) // take 16 bits each time
{
    std::string temp = binaryString.substr(i * 16, 16);
    std::bitset<16> temp2(temp);
    originalBack += temp2.to_ulong();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works great however slower than Jain's solution due to substringing in each iteration, so I'll accept the faster solution.